# Bringing a WPF border to front - a part of TextBox's autosuggestion project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a few issues with my autosuggestion project - I went with having a layout like this :

```
<Border Margin="30,125,44,77" BorderBrush="Black"   
    BorderThickness="1" Background="White">
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Name="resultStack"></StackPanel>
</Border>
```

To display items of my autosuggestion list. The autosuggestion part works just fine but I have a problem with the layout. When I launch my window, both the border and scroll viewer elements are behind all the other parts of my window...

Before autosuggest fires :

[image]

After autosuggest fires :

[image]

This is obviously not what I wanted. I want both the border and scrollviewer elements to be in front of all other elements.

If more code has to be provided for this problem to be solved, please let me know.

Comment: I can't test this at the moment, but I would look into using `Popup` or playing with the `ZIndex`. Doing a popup would seem like the best choice. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/wpf/wpf_popup.htm

Comment: So I'd just put all the contents located inside (including) Border inside a Popup and I should do fine?

Comment: For the most part. You'd need to give it hints as to where to display, but that tutorial I linked should get you started.

Comment: Nevermind I just added a Zindex to border and it worked. That way I didn't have to rebind any controls for display :) Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the ZIndex tip from user TyCobb worked for me. I could've used a lower value if I didn't have other ZIndexes assigned in other places.

```
<Border Margin="30,125,44,77" Panel.ZIndex="5"
    BorderThickness="1" Background="White" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Border.BorderBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush Color="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderColorKey}}"/>
    </Border.BorderBrush>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <StackPanel Name="resultStack"></StackPanel>
        </ScrollViewer>
 </Border>
```